# How many years have passed between "The colour of magic" and "Rising Steam"?

Tags: discworld

Well, its hard to expect scientific accuracy from Discworld series, but can we at least speculate?
We know that between "The fifth Elephant" and "Rising Steam" passed about 8-9 years (Sybil just found that she is pregnant in the former and young Sam is about 8 in the latter). We know that some time had to pass between "The Colour of Magic" and "Mort" because Ysabel has grown up, but she was living in the land of Death where "time is irrelevant", but we know that at least 16 years has passed between "Mort" and "Soul Music" (Susan is 16 and she spent most of her life in normal time) and then in her 20s in "Hogfather" and "Thief of Time".

So skipping the "Pyramids" and "Small Gods", that both happen completely out of other series, how many years has passed between the earliest (in universe)and latest Discworld book?

Comment: http://www.lspace.org/books/timeline/dw-timeline.html - Approx 75

Comment: Thanks @Richard, I've found it too. Should I close the question?

Comment: http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Discworld_Timeline

Comment: Personally, I'd have a good read and consider self-answering.

Comment: Out of curiousity, you say "Lesser Gods"? Is that a lit. translation for you, or just misremembering?

Comment: @MacCooper Bit of both - I've read it translated to Polish where it was indeed as "Lesser" (as "smaller than most") not "Small", but of course the correct English name is "Small gods"

Answer (score 3):

Since @Richard posted the short answer, I'll try to write more detailed one, based on the [those](http://www.lspace.org/books/timeline/dw-timeline.html) [two](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/index.php/Discworld_Timeline) timelines:

The first published book in the series is "The Colour of magic", that takes action around **1964** UC (University Calendar - based on founding UU).
The oldest in universe book is "Small Gods" that takes action around **1885** UC.
"Snuff" takes place in **1996**, "Rising Steam" about 1.5 years later (Young Sam is 6 in Snuff and about 7/8 in "Rising Steam").

So 1997 - 1964 = 33 years between first and last published book.

1997 - 1885 = 112 between oldest in universe book and the newest one.

Comment: Of course, *Thief of Time* (deliberately) throws a spanner in the works.